# Can Anyone Help me CONVERT Class Component To Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to convert class component to a function component but it is unsuccessful. This is the class component I want to convert:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      address: '',

      showingInfoWindow: false,
      activeMarker: {},
      selectedPlace: {},

      mapCenter: {
        lat: 49.2827291,
        lng: -123.1207375,
      },
    };
  }

  handleChange = (address) => {
    this.setState({ address });
  };

  handleSelect = (address) => {
    this.setState({ address });
    geocodeByAddress(address)
      .then((results) => getLatLng(results[0]))
      .then((latLng) => {
        console.log('Success', latLng);

        // update center state
        this.setState({ address });
        this.setState({ mapCenter: latLng });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error('Error', error));
  };
```

Here is my unsuccessful attempt:

```
const Location = () => {
  const [address, setAddress] = useState('')
  const [showingInfoWindow, setShowingInfoWindow] = useState(false)
  const [activeMarker, setActiveMarker] = useState({})
  const [selectedPlace, setSelectedPlace] = useState({})
  const [mapCenter, setMapCenter] = useState({lat: 49.2827291, lng: -123.1207375})


  handleChange = (address) => {
    this.setState({ address });
  };

  handleSelect = (address) => {
    this.setState({ address });
    geocodeByAddress(address)
      .then((results) => getLatLng(results[0]))
      .then((latLng) => {
        console.log('Success', latLng);

        // update center state
        this.setState({ address });
        this.setState({ mapCenter: latLng });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error('Error', error));
  };
  
    return (
```

Comment: This isn't even a full class component. Can you share the full example and also your attempt at converting to a function component, even if it isn't working, that's ok. Try to also include details about what isn't working and/or any errors you have.

Comment: i dont have any error also ok ill show my attempt, just a sec, also can i not send the full code, thats the only part i need to convert and i can do the rest thanks!

Comment: i hope you understand

Comment: Im sorry as i said im fairly new

Comment: Convert `this.setState({ address });` to `setAddress(address)` so the types match. Do similarly for the other state and updaters.

Comment: can you make it as an answer? with full code if you can

Comment: ```this.setState``` only works in class components. In functional components you have to use the functions you create with ```useState``` (e.g. ```setAddress```)

Comment: sorry i dont know what your saying

Comment: Take time for reading this : https://nimblewebdeveloper.com/blog/convert-react-class-to-function-component (Learn how to do it instead of asking people to do it for you)

Comment: im sorry im just 12 a-and i did say i tried to learn and i said im fairly new

Comment: i just started learning react just a week ago

Comment: BY THE WAY, isnt STACKOVERFLOW mostly for asking people to help???? so why complain that i ask to help. i tried doing it myself first

Comment: SO is a resource for help for specific issues, not a replacement for learning from official documentation and tutorials. SO isn't a code writing service. I'm happy you are getting into coding. Just keep up the learning. It will come.

Comment: Thank you everyone for giving me tips, lessons, and answers!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how your component would look like.

```
function Compo() {
  const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
  const [showingInfoWindow, setShowingInfoWindow] = useState(false);
  const [activeMarker, setActiveMarker] = useState({});
  const [selectedPlace, setSelectedPlace] = useState({});
  const [mapCenter, setMapCenter] = useState({lat: 49.2827291, lng: -123.1207375});

  const handleChange = (address) => {
    setAddress(address);
  };
  const handleSelect = (address) => {
    setAddress(address);
    geocodeByAddress(address)
      .then((results) => getLatLng(results[0]))
      .then((latLng) => {
        console.log("Success", latLng);

        // update center state
        setAddress(address);
        setMapCenter(latLng);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error("Error", error));
  };

  return (...);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is something that will look like in the functional component of you class component. Most probably your componentDidMount will be changed with useEffect() hook and state will be defined with useState().

```
function YouClassName(props){
const [address,setAddress] = useState('');
const [showingInfoWindow,setshowingInfoWindow] = useState(false);
const [activeMarker,setactiveMarker] = useState({});
const [selectedPlace,setselectedPlace] = useState({});
const [mapCenter,setmapCenter] = useState({});
   
useEffect(async ()=>{
setmapCenter({lat: 49.2827291,lng: -123.1207375})
},[])

  const handleChange = (address) => {
    //this.setState({ address });
     setAddress( address ); //Replace everywhere like this
  };

  const handleSelect = (address) => {
    setAddress( address );
    geocodeByAddress(address)
      .then((results) => getLatLng(results[0]))
      .then((latLng) => {
        console.log('Success', latLng);

        // update center state
        setAddress( address ); 
        setmapCenter( latLng );
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error('Error', error));
  };
return (
    <div >
       //Your HTML content goes
    </div>
  )
}
```

Instead of render your function component will return the html only.
You can check for hooks in the React guide for further assistance.

Thanks

Comment: I have not replaced all this.state with set methods you can do that by your own apart from that let me know if there are any errors. By the way not an issue. Thanks

Comment: Just try to change and let me know if there are any errors I thought you should try yourself that much :)

Comment: btw can you tell me which is best practice... the one on the top answer or your answer? i always like to check which is better way to do things

Comment: give it a thumbs up if things are fine for you. :)

Comment: @Sanjeev_gupta2812 `this.setState` in functional components?

Comment: @TechySharnav Ahh I think I should change/edit this by myself. I have already provided comment that this.setState has to be replaced with methods everywhere but I think no one gives an eye on that. :)

Comment: @Sanjeev_gupta2812 i fixed all the errors butsadly it didnt worked, it was giving my [object Object] on my input.... But ill give upvote for giving effort :)

Comment: Now you can check this again. And by the way both are fine I have shown you an extra use of useEffect so that you could know to set the value at the time of component is mounted. Thanks